# How to return the value of self in a class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, self

I have a class called `buttongen` which generates buttons based on the rooms within a building. The rooms will be assessed and have the results stored in a database. How can I return the value of the text on the button to store in a variable? Each time I try to store the results for the rooms its giving the error `TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'i' and 'row'`.

EDIT: Included the section of code where the building is searched and the buttons are generated

```py
    def search():
        global screen13
        global btn
        screen13 = Tk()
        screen13.geometry("300x250")
        screen13.title("Rooms")
        sitename3_info = sitename.get().strip()
        if sitename3_info:
            cursor = cnn.cursor()
            # combine the two SQL statements into one
            sql = ("SELECT roomname FROM rooms, Sites "
                   "WHERE rooms.siteID_fk2 = Sites.siteID AND siteName = %s")
            cursor.execute(sql, [sitename3_info])
            rooms = cursor.fetchall()
            # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
            for w in screen13.winfo_children():
                w.destroy()
            if rooms:
                for i, row in enumerate(rooms):
                    buttongen(i, row)
            else:
                Label(screen13, text="No room found").grid()

    class buttongen():
        def __init__(self,i,row):
            # creates a self generated amount of buttons which correspond to the amount of rooms in the table.
            self.i = i
            self.row = row
    
            self.roomname = self.row[0]
            self.btn = Button(screen13, text = self.roomname, command=lambda :[print(self.roomname), action()])
            self.btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
        def showroomname(self):
            print(self.roomname)
```

how can I store what text is on the button in `roomclicked_info = buttongen()`

Comment: Your ```__init__``` expecting 2 elements ```i``` and ```row```.

Comment: Your problem is originated where you create the instance. You did not show us that part of the code. In addition, add the full error traceback to the question.

Comment: When you call a class to create an instance of it, the return value is automatically `self`. The class' `__init__()` is called automatically when you do this, however when you called the class, you didn't pass the required `i` and `row` parameters which is the cause of the error. You need to study classes more and get a better understanding of how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

the right code may like this:

```
i = 10   # the i you want
row = 10 # the row you want
roomclicked_info = buttongen(i, row)
```

class buttongen need 2 required positional arguments.

Comment: I can't specify the i and row I want as that changes every time. The buttons are not fixed they change depending on the building which is why I used `self.i` and `self.row`

Comment: @Julia then *why did you make them part of the `__init__` signature*?

Answer (score 2):

To initialize the object of **`buttongen()`** you need to pass the two required parameters as defined in `def __init__(self,i,row):` the **`i`** and **`row`**.

As you are creating the object with `roomclicked_info = buttongen()`, you are not specifying the `i` and `row` parameters in `buttongen()`. You can pass the values of `i` and `row` here, like `roomclicked_info = buttongen(i, row)`.

Comment: even when `roomclicked_info = buttongen(I,row)` I still receive errors such as I and row are not defined.

Comment: Ya that's obvious. You have to specify what the i & row is.
As i see in your code self.roomname = self.row[0], then the row is a kind of iterable variable like (list or tuple)

Comment: Would it be better to make a list called roomclick under `def showroomname(self)` and use `append(self.roomname)`

Comment: Don't even think about it. You won't reach to `def showroomname(self)` untill you fix `def __init__(self, i, row)`. You don't have to find issues under `class buttongen():`. You need to focus of object initialisation, you need to understand what is **i** and **row**. issue is in what is **row**, you need to understand it completely before proceeding anywhere.